# Attachments can not be sent out through email

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments, email

I am trying to send an email with attachment from my android app. But the email somehow goes out without the attachment, even though the file exists. In the email sending view, it shows the attachment (with file size even), but after sending, on the receiver side, there is no attachment. Any idea why?

```
private void copyFileToExternal() throws IOException {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "data/com.dw.inspectionhelperNSTC/databases/Inspection.db";
            String backupDBPath = "Inspection_backup.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                        .getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                        .getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("currentDB does not exists");
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "NO SDcard so unable to send the database backup",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("sdcard cant write");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

private void sendEmail(String email) {
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    // Adding the inspection DB;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Inspection_backup.db");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
    uris.add(path);
    // Adding the stacttrack file with uncaught expection
    File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            Constant.STACKTRACE_FILE);
    Uri path2 = Uri.fromFile(file2);
    uris.add(path2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "inspection database");
    String to[] = { email };
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "sending inspection database for reporting");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."),
            1222);
}
```

Comment: Your current db path is wrong its should bt Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/com.dw.inspe....." etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void sendMailWithIntent(String emailTo,
                                   String subject, String emailText, List<String> filePaths) {
        try {
            //need to "send multiple" to get more than one attachment
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    Util.extractEmails(emailTo));
//            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC,
//                    new String[]{emailCC});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            //has to be an ArrayList
            if (filePaths != null) {
                //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
                for (String file : filePaths) {
                    File fileIn = new File(file);
                    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                    uris.add(u);
                }
            }
            emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...");
            activity.startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new ShowToast(context, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

> Call it like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(TO_ATTACH_ONE);
        list.add(TO_ATTACH_TWO);
        sendMailTest.sendMailWithIntent(toAddresses, subject, body, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendEmail(String filename)
    {

        String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator+ folderName +File.separator+ filename;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        i.setType("*/*");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Body");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Email Found", 5000);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help you out.